# Matching closest values panel data Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, finance

I am currently working on a project involving financial data. I have a data frame containing a number of fundamental variables as well as stock returns for many different companies, just like this:

```
           year     ticker      tot_assets      return
0          1999       AAPL          10.345      0.1294
1          2000       AAPL          10.988      0.1577
2          2001       AAPL          12.003      0.0782
..          ...        ...             ...         ...
34521      2017       GMBO           0.893      0.2209
34522      2018       GMBO           1.206      0.1001
..          ...        ...             ...         ...
200344     2012         ZZ           3.789      0.0032
200344     2013         ZZ           3.021     -0.0346
```

What I have been trying to do without success is, to match each company `ticker`, for each year, with another one in the df based on the closest `tot_assets` value in the same year. Thus create two new columns, where one has the `ticker` of the matched company as well as its `returns` for that year.

So it should look like something like this:

```
           year     ticker   tot_assets   return   m_ticker   m_return
0          1999       AAPL       10.345   0.1294         AA     0.0890
1          2000       AAPL       10.988   0.1577         AA     0.1666
2          2001       AAPL       12.003   0.0782       TSLA     0.3470
..          ...        ...          ...      ...        ...        ...
34521      2017       GMBO        0.893   0.2209        AIR     0.0032
34522      2018       GMBO        1.206   0.1001       CECE     0.1123
..          ...        ...          ...      ...        ...        ...
200344     2012         ZZ        3.789   0.0032       ASKI     0.0432
200344     2013         ZZ        3.021  -0.0346       ASKI     0.0339
```

I hope I was clear enough in my explanation :P Maybe that's the reason why I have been having troubles! I cannot show you the df because it has more 200'000 observations - but I hope that the concepts above help :)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A sample output dataframe will be helpful. I did not quite get your explanation.

Comment: "based on the closest tot_assets value in the same year" you sample data does not have any overlapping years

Comment: @Vishnudev hope this way it helps :)

Comment: @Chris I do, but the df is too large to post here, for this reason I have put the ... , so that is clear that the df is larger than what I have posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`merge` within year and remove any tickers that merge with themself. Then determine the absolute difference in `'total_assets'`. By sorting and dropping duplicates we keep only the closest match for each ['ticker', 'year'] in the original DataFrame.

#### Sample Data

```
           year     ticker      tot_assets      return
0          1999       AAPL          10.345      0.1294
1          2000       AAPL          10.988      0.1577
34521      1999       GMBO           0.893      0.2209
34522      2000       GMBO           1.206      0.1001
200344     1999         ZZ           3.789      0.0032
200344     2000         ZZ           3.021     -0.0346
```

#### Code

```
df = df.merge(df, on='year', suffixes=['', '_closest']).query('ticker != ticker_closest')
df['diff'] = (df['tot_assets'] - df['tot_assets_closest']).abs()
df = df.sort_values('diff').drop_duplicates(['year', 'ticker'])
```

#### Output:

```
    year ticker  tot_assets  return ticker_closest  tot_assets_closest  return_closest   diff
14  2000   GMBO       1.206  0.1001             ZZ               3.021         -0.0346  1.815
16  2000     ZZ       3.021 -0.0346           GMBO               1.206          0.1001  1.815
5   1999   GMBO       0.893  0.2209             ZZ               3.789          0.0032  2.896
7   1999     ZZ       3.789  0.0032           GMBO               0.893          0.2209  2.896
2   1999   AAPL      10.345  0.1294             ZZ               3.789          0.0032  6.556
11  2000   AAPL      10.988  0.1577             ZZ               3.021         -0.0346  7.967
```

---

The above is going to be a very large merge. Another alternative is to use `pd.merge_asof` with `allow_exact_matches=False`. Becasue `tot_assets` is a float, it's highly unlikely for two different tickers to have the exact same value, so `allow_exact_matches=False` essentially prevents the same ticker from merging with itself. However, if there is another ticker with exactly the same tot_assets, we will miss that with this method.

```
df = df.sort_values('tot_assets')
df = (pd.merge_asof(df, df.add_suffix('_closest'), 
                    left_by='year', right_by='year_closest',
                    left_on='tot_assets', right_on='tot_assets_closest',
                    direction='nearest',
                    allow_exact_matches=False)
        .drop(columns='year_closest'))
```